# The permission READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE is not available for TelephonyManager.getSubscriberId,

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-permissions, telephonymanager

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, CALL_REQUEST_CODE);
    }



public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == CALL_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            subscriberId = telephonyManager.getSubscriberId();
        }
```

I have declared permission for READ_PHONE_STATE and in the manifest as well. But getSubscriberId() throws error saying "The user 10171 does not meet the requirements to access device identifiers." I require subscriberId to track mobile network data usage. The permission READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE is not available in manifest  which is the only way to use for NetworkStatsManager.queryDetailsForUid.
can someone pls help in resolving this, thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Due to security purposes Android restricted the use of TelephonyManager class.

From Android 10 (API Level 29) you don't get any information using TelephonyManager Class for more details please read all the info from below link

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids#java

Answer (score 0):

Android 10 (API level 29) adds restrictions for non-resettable identifiers, which include both IMEI and serial number. Your app must be a device or profile owner app, have special carrier permissions, or have the READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE privileged permission in order to access these identifiers.

You can go through this link to see if there's something which can help you - https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids